# UPdating XML, getting "Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object"

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to update 3 pieces of data in an XML document but getting an "Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object" error.  This is the XML file format I am trying to update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" standalone="true"?>
<ExportSettings xmlns="CompanyName" ExportName="Data Export" Dataset="TestName">
  <General>
     <AsOfDate>03/31/15</AsOfDate>
     <PriceDate>03/31/16</PriceDate>  
  </General>
  <Source>
      <Set>Set Name</Set>
  </Source>
</ExportSettings>
```

This is the C# code that is throwing the error:

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            {
                string strAsOfDate = dateTimePickerAsOfDate.Text;
                string strPriceDate = dateTimePickerPriceDate.Text;
                string strSetName = txtboxSet.Text;

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(strXMLfilepath);
                XmlNode General;
                XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
                General = root.SelectSingleNode("/ExportSettings/General");
                General["AsOfDate"].InnerText = strAsOfDate;
                General["PriceDate"].InnerText = strPriceDate;
                XmlNode Source;
                Source = root.SelectSingleNode("/ExportSettings/Source");
                Source["Set"].InnerText = strSetName;
                doc.Save(strXMLfilepath);

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see the problem?  I am not very familiar with updating XML so there may be something basic wrong here.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  You should be able to easily debug this and see which variable is null.

Comment: General["AsOfDate"].InnerText = strAsOfDate; 

Also, strAsOfDate is not null when the exception is thrown.

Comment: When you place a breakpoint on that line, is the "General" variable null?  If not then the "General["AsOfDate]" is failing and returning null meaning the .InnerText will throw the exception you are seeing.

Comment: Your elements are in the `CompanyName` namespace and you are asking for elements that don't belong to any namespace. As a result the SelectSingleNode returns null and any operation on this value results in a NullReferenceException.

Comment: OK, so General does remain null.  The debugger skips over the "XmlNode General;" line, then throws an exception after it looks at "General["AsOfDate"].InnerText = strAsOfDate;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged this locally and as Pawel suggests, you need to make some changes regarding namespaces:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        {
            string strAsOfDate = dateTimePickerAsOfDate.Text;
            string strPriceDate = dateTimePickerPriceDate.Text;
            string strSetName = txtboxSet.Text;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(strXMLfilepath);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "CompanyName");

            XmlNode General;
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            General = root.SelectSingleNode("//ab:General", nsmgr);
            General["AsOfDate"].InnerText = strAsOfDate;
            General["PriceDate"].InnerText = strPriceDate;

            doc.Save(strXMLfilepath);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excep)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why does it skip over XmlNode General;?  General is null which I think is what is throwing the error.

Comment: XmlNode General; just declares the variable.  It gets set at General = root.SelectSingleNode("//ab:General", nsmgr);  Did you add in the two new lines of code above and also change root.SelectSingleNode("//ab:General", nsmgr);??

Comment: Yes...I copied and pasted your code but it is still throwing the error right after General["AsOfDate"].InnerText = strAsOfDate;

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was in the namespace, I forgot to change something back to how the real XML file was.  Thank you for your help!